# Is there a better way of debugging javascript in MVC3 application other than adding debugger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to debug javascript in my .cshtml file and adding "debugger;" is troublesome.

Is there a better way of debugging javascript in .cshtml files being debugged under VS2010?

Comment: if your script runs in a browser you can use `window.console`

Answer (score 6):

The best way for me has always been to just open the site in a browser and use the browser's development tools. All of them allow setting breakpoints, watch variables etc. these days.